# creating a softlink to a file in another directory in linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell

1. Created a directory named D1, created a file f1 in the same directory
2. Created an empty directory named D2, created a softlink for  f1(file) which is in d1(directory) and stored it in d2(directory).
   The command I used: `ln -s d1/f1 d2/sf1` (sf1 is name of soft_link file )
3. Moved to D2 using command `cd d2`, tried to open the created sf1, it is showing me that "No such file or directory"

```
ln -s d1/f1 d2/sf1
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The the symbolic link behaves a little funny when you are not in the target directory, `d2`.  The path to the file needs to be relative to `d2`. The command is you need is `ln -s ../d1/f1 d2/sf1`.

```
$ mkdir d1 d2
$ touch d1/f1
$  ln -s d1/f1 d2/sf1
$ ls -l d2
total 0
lrwxr-xr-x  1 wderezin  admin  5 Sep 18 08:04 sf1 -> d1/f1
$ file d2/sf1
d2/sf1: broken symbolic link to d1/f1
```

```
$ rm d2/sf1
$ ln -s ../d1/f1 d2/sf1
$ ls -l d2
total 0
lrwxr-xr-x  1 wderezin  admin  8 Sep 18 08:04 sf1 -> ../d1/f1
$ file d2/sf1
d2/sf1: empty
```

Comment: thanks alot,
am haiving a doubt,after entering the command " ln -s d1/f1 d2/sf1",and moved to d2,there i can find the softlink "sf1",but i couldn't open that using cat sf1,y it happened like that,can u plz elobrate the issue by sparing some time,as am new to linux
thanks and regards